# Redux useReducer and mapDispatchToProps not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-reducer

I'm building a react app using redux for state management.
Inside the SearchField component I am using useReducer for handle the search field inputs (cityField and countryField).
When i submit  the  fetchData function runs and sends a request to an API.

the SearchField component code:

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { SET_CITY_FIELD, SET_COUNTRY_FIELD } from '../../redux/search-field/search-field.types';
import { reducer, INITIAL_STATE } from "../../redux/search-field/search-field.reducer";
import { fetchData } from '../../redux/weather-api-data/data.actions';

import { SearchFieldContainer, SearchInput, OptionalField, FormComponent } from './search-field.styles';

const SearchField = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, INITIAL_STATE);
    const { cityField, countryField } = state;

    const onFormSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        cityField.length < 1 ?
          alert('Please insert a city')
        :
        fetchData(cityField, countryField);
      }     

    return (
        <SearchFieldContainer>
            <FormComponent onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
                <SearchInput type="search" placeholder="Search City" aria-label="Search"
                    onChange={event => dispatch({ type: SET_CITY_FIELD, payload: event.target.value })}   
                />
            </FormComponent>
            <FormComponent className='country-form' onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
                <SearchInput className='country' type="search" placeholder="Country" aria-label="Search"
                    onChange={event => dispatch({ type: SET_COUNTRY_FIELD, payload: event.target.value })}
                />
                <OptionalField>OPTIONAL</OptionalField>
            </FormComponent>        
        </SearchFieldContainer>
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchData: (cityField, countryField) => dispatch(fetchData(cityField, countryField))
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchField);
```

The problem is that when the OnFormSubmit function is called, the fetchData function does not send any request and there is no errors in the console. The searchField and countryField data are stored correctly (or at least if I show them in the console I get the actual values). The fetchData function was previously located in the App and worked correctly.
I thank in advance anyone who gives me an answer and tries to find the solution.

The fetchData code:

```
export const fetchData = (cityField, countryField) => {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchCurrentDataRequest())
    axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityField},${countryField}&units=metric&appid=MY_API_KEY`)
        .then(response => {
            const currentData = response.data                
            dispatch(fetchCurrentDataSuccess(currentData));
            const { lat, lon } = currentData.coord                
            dispatch(fetchDailyDataRequest())
            axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=metric&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid=MY_API_KEY`)
                .then(response => {
                    const dailyData = response.data.daily
                    dispatch(fetchDailyDataSuccess(dailyData))
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    const errorMessage = error.message
                    dispatch(fetchCurrentDataFailure(errorMessage))
                })            
        })
        .catch(error => {
            const errorMessage = error.message
            alert('No results found')
            dispatch(fetchCurrentDataFailure(errorMessage))
        })
}
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through your code, starting in `onFormSubmit`? Would at least tell you where it's going wrong. Without knowing the result of that or seeing what's in `fetchData` it's hard to help.

Comment: PS: while it's fine to use both, the reducer passed to `useReducer` is nothing to do with Redux - it's an alternative to `useState` in managing local state, not whole-application state like Redux is used for. I detect possible confusion in that the reducer you're passing to `useReducer` is stored in a folder called `redux`...

Comment: You need to create a reproducible code in https://codesandbox.io so we could help you find your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved using useDispatch hook instead of mapdispatchToProps, so the new code is:

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchData } from '../../redux/weather-api-data/data.actions';
import { reducer, INITIAL_STATE } from '../../redux/search-field/search-field.reducer';
import { SET_CITY_FIELD, SET_COUNTRY_FIELD } from '../../redux/search-field/search-field.types';

import { SearchFieldContainer, SearchInput, OptionalField, FormComponent } from './search-field.styles';

const SearchField = () => {
    const dispatchData = useDispatch();
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, INITIAL_STATE);
    const { cityField, countryField } = state;

    const onFormSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        cityField.length < 1 ?
          alert('Please insert a city')
        :
        dispatchData(fetchData(cityField, countryField));
      }     

    return (
        <SearchFieldContainer>
            <FormComponent onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
                <SearchInput type="search" placeholder="Search City" aria-label="Search"
                    onChange={event => dispatch({ type: SET_CITY_FIELD, payload: event.target.value })}   
                />
            </FormComponent>
            <FormComponent className='country-form' onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
                <SearchInput className='country' type="search" placeholder="Country" aria-label="Search"
                    onChange={event => dispatch({ type: SET_COUNTRY_FIELD, payload: event.target.value })}
                />
                <OptionalField>OPTIONAL</OptionalField>
            </FormComponent>        
        </SearchFieldContainer>
    )
}

export default SearchField;
```